# How can I use bootstrap-table to get data from webapi (need [Authorize])

Tags: bootstrap-table

How can I use bootstrap-table to get data from webapi (need [Authorize])

[image: pic1]

Error:

[image: pic2]

Comment: Try adding the `ajaxOptions` property to your `bootstrapTable` call. `ajaxOptions: {username:"yourusername",password:"yourpassword"}` For reference see http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11960692/1487413 ... please let us know if it works!